# Ehcache + Hibernate Log Output

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am receiving Eh-cache logging output when using it with Hibernate 2nd Level cache - i do not undertand the output and what it might mean. It is being printed to the logs  a lot.

```
 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment] put added 0 on heap
 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment] put updated, deleted 0 on heap
```

Could anyone shed some light on what this might mean? My Second level cache appears to be working, according to a print of the statistics...

```
INFO [com.atlaschase.falcon.commands.domain.AircraftCommandResolutionService] [  name = aircraftCache cacheHits = 824 onDiskHits = 0 offHeapHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 824 misses = 182 onDiskMisses = 182 offHeapMisses = 0 inMemoryMisses = 182 size = 91 averageGetTime = 1.0745527 evictionCount = 0 ]
```

Any help would be appreciated ..

Simon

Comment: Oh - can someone also confirm that the 'averageGetTime' is in milliseconds and not seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This output is generated by [DiskStore](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/storage-options#DiskStore), IIRC enabled by default in EhCache. Basically EhCache overflows cached data from memory to disk. If you want to disable this functionality, set `overflowToDisk` property to `flase`:

```
<cache name="..." overflowToDisk="false"
```

> Oh - can someone also confirm that the 'averageGetTime' is in milliseconds and not seconds?

Confirmed, milliseconds. Although the [JavaDoc of `Statistics.getAverageGetTime()`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Statistics.html#getAverageGetTime%28%29) is *slightly* confusing:

> [...] Because ehcache support JDK1.4.2, each get time uses System.currentTimeMilis, rather than nanoseconds. The accuracy is thus limited.

I found the following code in `LiveCacheStatisticsImpl`:

```
public float getAverageGetTimeMillis() {
    //...
    return (float) totalGetTimeTakenMillis.get() / hitCount;
}
```